# Confuse about Assembly CALL,RET Statement

Tags: assembly, stack, nasm, masm

I want to know when "CALL" instrucion execute. It first push return address on stack or function arguments?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CALL` does not push arguments at all. It pushes only the return address. You are responsible to push the arguments on your own, which happens before `CALL`, obviously. For example:

```
    push 2
    push 1
    push "%d"
    call printf
next_instruction:
    add esp, 12
```

When entering the `printf` function, assuming a near call in 32-bit, the stack will look like this:

```
esp+0:  address of next_instruction
esp+4:  address of "%d"
esp+8:  1
esp+12: 2
```

**Edit:** Regarding the order of the arguments, extending on what @Martin has said:

The interpretation of what's there on the stack is a contract between the caller and the callee (named 'calling convention'), and it depends on a lot of things, including language, architecture, compiler, and more. For C on x86 the arguments are pushed from the last to the first. So the above assembly snippet corresponds to the translated C statement:

```
printf("%d", 1, 2);
```

If you look at the stack above, you see that since we pushed the arguments in the reverse order, they got ordered from the first to the last relative to `esp`. This way `printf` can read the first argument `"%d"` without knowing how much arguments will follow, and then determine the rest from the format string. Also since in the C calling convention the caller is responsible for removing the arguments from the stack (the `next_instruction`), passing more arguments than necessary is harmless (although it is undefined behavior according to the standard).

Comment: So it mean sir if i call blah_blah('bye' , 'dare').first argument get pushed on stack (dare and bye).then return address. Right?

Comment: Correct. The calling function does a "push" for the two arguments (dare and bye) and then performs a "call". The order the arguments are pushed depends on the calling convention. For C programming language the last argument is pushed first and the first argument is pushed last.

Answer (score 2):

If the function returns an object too large to fit in a register, then space for the returned object is preallocated:

```
        sub     esp,sizeof object
        push    ecx
        push    eax
        call    example
        add     esp,8     ;restore stack
;                         ;esp is now pointer to object
        add     esp,sizeof object    ;restore stack once object no longer needed
```